# Problem installing react-native stripe sdk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I installed react-native stripe sdk with the following command:

```
npm install @stripe/stripe-react-native
```

After I try to build the app I get the following two errors:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\xampp\htdocs\SoFood\node_modules\@stripe\stripe-react-native\android\build.gradle' line: 18

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':stripe_stripe-react-native'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'kotlin-android']
   > The current Gradle version 5.4.1 is not compatible with the Kotlin Gradle plugin. Please use Gradle 6.1 or newer, or the previous version of the Kotlin plugin.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':stripe_stripe-react-native'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 40s
```

Any idea what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that your current version of Gradle is not compatible with the package requirements.
Try to upgrade the version of your Gradle.

How to do that :
In android/build.gradle you have to edit this line

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.y.z'
```

Modify the x and y and z with the version they suggested. for example :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.1.0'
```

Edit it with Android Studio then click Sync now